# Atmega328P Watch Dog Timer - Delay Issue

Tags: microcontroller, avr, interrupts, watchdog, atmega328p

I am trying to give delay of 0.5 seconds on 13 pin of the arduino using Watch Dog timer interrupt, the code complies and works fine but the led  is blinking so rapidly that it seems like it is blinking at a delay of 50ms not with a delay of 0.5 second. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<avr/interrupt.h>
#include<avr/wdt.h>

int main(void)
{
  cli();
  wdt_reset();

  WDTCSR |=(1<<WDP2) | (1<<WDP0);

  WDTCSR |= (1<<WDIE);
  WDTCSR |= (1<<WDE);

  sei();

  DDRB |= 0b00100000;

  PORTB |= 0b00000000;

  while(1)
  {

  }
}

ISR(WDT_vect) {

 PORTB ^= 0b00100000;

}
```

Comment: Try setting WDE to 0 rather than 1 - that should give you a 500ms interrupt with no system reset - with that code I would expect the system to reset every 500ms immediately after entering the ISR, and since you don't clear the interrupt flag, you enter that ISR immediately when you set WDIE after reset - toggling the pin.

Comment: Tried, still the problem is same. it is blinking so rapidly.

Comment: Are you sure you just don't need to clear the interrupt in the ISR?

Comment: The datasheet says "altera-
tions to the Watchdog set-up must follow timed sequences" w.r.t. the "Watchdog change enable bit (WDCE)" and also has example code. Why don't you use that?

Answer (score 2):

If I read the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) (p.54-55) correctly, you have to set the `WDCE` bit in `WDTCSR` to be able to change the prescaler. The default setting for the prescaler bits is `000` or about a 16 ms delay.

Also, if you set  both `WDE` and `WDIE`, the watchdog works in "Interrupt and System Reset Mode", where the first WD timeout triggers the interrupt, and a second one resets the device, unless the `WDIE` bit is set again after the interrupt. Or if you only want the interrupt, not the reset, just leave `WDE` unset.

So paraphrasing the example code, I think you'll want something like this:

```
cli();
WDTCSR |= (1<<WDCE);  /* enable change */
WDTCSR = (1<<WDIE) | (1<<WDP2) | (1<<WDP0);  /* enable interrupt and set prescaler */
sei();
```